# Few basic things unclear to me about inner product spaces and orthonormal basis

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, inner-products

Few things unclear to me about inner product spaces:

assume **V** is an inner product space with **B** orthonormal basis.
Why is it true that:

1. $$\langle x,y\rangle  = \langle[x]_{B} , [y]_B \rangle{st}$$  when the first is some inner product and the second has st on it to mark that it is the standard inner product
2. $$[Ci]^{*}_{B} [Cj]_{B}  = \langle[Ci]_{B}, [Cj]_{B} \rangle{st}$$
   when Ci and Cj are columns in a matrix

thank you very much!

Comment: by $[x]_B$ do you mean coordinate of $x$ with respect to the orthonormal basis?
If yes, just write down $x=x_1*e_1+x_2*e_2+ \dots x_n e_n$ and recall that $\langle e_i,e_j \rangle = \delta_i^j$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Concering your first question:

If, say $B = \{ b_1, \dots, b_n \}$,
$x = \sum_{i=1}^n a_i e_i$ and $y = \sum_{i=1}^n b_i e_i$ and if you mean by $[x]_B$ the tuple $(a_1, \dots, a_n)$ and by $[y]_B$ the tuple $(b_1, \dots, b_n)$, then
$\langle x, y \rangle
= \langle \sum_{i=1}^n a_i e_i, \sum_{j=1}^n b_j e_j \rangle
= \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n a_i b_j \langle e_i, e_j \rangle
= \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n a_i b_j \delta_{i,j}
= \sum_{i=1}^n a_i b_i
= \langle [x]_B, [y]_B \rangle_{st}$.

As for the second, if $C = (c_{ij})_{i,j}$, then
$[Ci] = (c_{1i}, \dots, c_{ni})$
and
$[Cj] = (c_{1j}, \dots, c_{nj})$.

Then you get
$[Ci]^*[Cj] = \sum_{k=1}^n c_{ki} c_{kj} = \langle[Ci],[Cj]\rangle_{st}$

Remark: I suppressed the subindex $B$ here, since I do not see any reason for it.